# ReSharper: "Go To Declaration in .NET Reflector"

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, .net-reflector

Do you know of a ReSharper 5.1 plugin that allows me to go to the declaration of a class or member that I do not have the source code for using .NET Reflector?

Usually Reflector itself has this feature already (rightclick-> "Open in .NET Reflector") but unfortunately this feature does not work with resharper. The explanation for this can be read [here](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=11451).

Now the ideal solution would be if resharper could do this for me with a plugin. In earlier versions of resharper, wasn't there a resharper powertoy that could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the ReflectorNavigator in the ReSharper PowerToys: http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/

Comment: Unfortuantely it is only available for 5.0. It doesn't seem to work for 5.1.

Comment: What do you mean? I made the 5.1 release a few days ago. Is it giving you issues?
http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/releases/view/50065

Comment: @HadiHariri is this still the preferred way in R# > 8, tx!

Comment: We have dotPeek now built in to ReSharper, which provides all this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Try to uncheck option "**Enable navigation to external sources**" at Resharper Options -> Tools -> External Sources or leave it enabled, but move "Object browser" item to top of the list. Works for me.